# How to place two figures in one column, and then another figure in the 2nd column with double the size?

Tags: floats

I am trying to do as described in the title. This code below returns

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}}
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}
}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
```

[image]

but what I would like is the following figure

[image]

I used mini pages but the figures are all now on top of each other. How do I fix the code?

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}}
    \end{tikzpicture}}\\
    \subfloat[]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: Used two minipages side by side.

Comment: @Bernard i use minipages but i get the figures on top of each other. How do i fix the code

Comment: Try with slightly smaller minipages (say 0.45\textwidth) and `\hfill` between them.

Answer (score 1):

You have two columns in the outer `\hbox`, each of them is `\vbox`. You have two objects (`\hbox`es) in the first `\vbox` and single `\hbox` in the second `\vbox`. Each inner `\hbox` includes an image. You can set vertical `\kern` inside `\vbox` and horizontal `\kern` inside `\hbox`. The material in `\hbox`es must be without unwanted spaces (end of lines). Your situation is:

```
\hbox{%
    \vbox{
        \hbox{...first small image...}
        \kern 5mm % vertical space between images
        \hbox{... second small image ...}  
    }%
    \kern 5mm % horizontal space between columns 
    \vbox{
        \hbox{... third high image ...}
    }%
}
```

If you want to compute the vertical space between small images automatically (depending on the height of the third image), then you can use `\valign` primitive:

```
\hbox{\valign{#\cr
   \hbox{... first image ...}\vfil
   \hbox{... second image ...}\cr 
   \noalign{\kern 5mm} % the space between columns
   \hbox{... third height image...}\cr
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aligning bottoms is easy.  To align tops, use `\raisebox{-\height}{...}` on each.

BTW, I threw out a lot of functionless code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \par\vskip\floatsep
    \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

---

Just for fun, this aligns both the tops **and** the bottoms.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\sbox0{\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}}%
\sbox1{\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-b}}}%
\sbox2{\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}}}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \usebox0
    \par\vspace{\dimexpr \ht2+\dp2-\ht0-\dp0-\ht1-\dp1}%
    \usebox1
\end{minipage}\hfill
\usebox2
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```