# How can I create this layout of 3 subfigures?

Tags: graphics

How can I create a figure with three subfigures oriented as shown in the image below?[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640300/4427 help? Use `\subcaptionbox` instead of `\subcaptionbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I have done this before, but can't seem to find it.  (Later) I found [it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611153/how-to-place-two-figures-in-one-column-and-then-another-figure-in-the-2nd-colum/611178?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C51.4921#611178), but this solution is more elegant.

First, you measure the height of the subfigure on the left.  You create a minipage with the same height and put the other two subfigures inside, separated by `\vfill`.  So long as the two subfigures on the right together are smaller than the one on the left, you will align both tops and bottoms.  The [b] options will align the bottom captions (last baseline).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}% measuer height with caption
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4in]{example-image-a}% some argitrary height
  \caption{caption 1}
\end{subfigure}}%
\usebox0\hfill\begin{minipage}[b][\ht0][s]{\wd0}% s=stretch
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{caption 2}
  \end{subfigure}\par
  \vfill% very important
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{caption 3}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version shrinks one or more of the images to fit.  While the `2\lineskip` terms seems ad hoc, setting `\lineskip=0pt` does affect the size.

Note the braces around `\resizebox` and `\scalebox`.  This is to protect all the box registers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfmath}% or tikz
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\dimen1}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}% default width
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=\dimen1]{example-image-10x16}}% images
\sbox1{\includegraphics[width=\dimen1]{example-image-b}}%
\sbox2{\includegraphics[width=\dimen1]{example-image-c}}%
\sbox3{\begin{subfigure}[b]{\dimen1}
  %\hrule height0pt% baseline here
  \caption{caption 1}
\end{subfigure}}% captions
\sbox4{\begin{subfigure}[b]{\dimen1}
  %\hrule height0pt% baseline here
  \caption{caption 2}
\end{subfigure}}%
\sbox5{\begin{subfigure}[b]{\dimen1}
  %\hrule height0pt% baseline here
  \caption{caption 3}
\end{subfigure}}% captions
\setlength{\dimen2}{\dimexpr \ht1+\ht2+\ht4+\dp4+\floatsep+2\lineskip}% right height
\ifdim\ht0>\dimen2
  \def\scale{1}%
\else
  \dimen2=\ht0
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\ht0-\ht4-\dp4-\floatsep-2\lineskip)/(\ht1+\ht2)}%
\fi
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimen1}
  \centering
  {\resizebox{!}{\dimen2}{\usebox0}}
  \usebox3
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimen1}
  \centering
  {\scalebox{\scale}{\usebox1}}
  \usebox4
  \vskip\floatsep
  {\scalebox{\scale}{\usebox2}}
  \usebox5
\end{minipage}    
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is task for TeX primitives `\hbox`, `\vbox`. If you know how these primitives work then there is no more problem. For example:

```
\def\figure#1#2{\vbox{\hbox{FIGURE #1}\medskip\hbox{\qquad#2}}}

\hbox to\hsize{\figure 1{(a) caption 1}\hss
               \vbox{\figure 2 {(b) caption 2}\bigskip
                     \figure 3 {(c) caption 3}}}

\bye
```

Of course, the text `FIGURE #1` should be replaced by creating a real figure. For example, you can use `\picw=.45\hsize \inspic{fig-#1.png}` if you are using OpTeX and if you have images `fig-1.png`, `fig-2.png` and `fig-3.png`.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to work when using just `\inspic fig-#1.png`... It just reads the first letter of the figure name and then complains that figure isn't found.

Comment: @user574859 `\inspic` has two variants of syntax: `\inspic file-name space` or `\inspic{file-name}`. Sorry, I didn't express that the file name must be terminated by space or enclosed in braces. I corrected my example.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. However, depending on the size of the 1st image, it's better to have a result such as the one in the image below (vertical centering). I'm still unsure about how to do that, so I opened a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/646996/258453

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, is that what You want?** taken from [very nice book](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}}\\ (a)
\end{tabular}\qquad % some space
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b.png}}\\ (b)
\\[0.1cm]
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c.png}}\\ (c)
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as a reminder, `subfig` is a very old and obsolete package which use is *not* recommended (even its direct successor is now obsolete). It'd be best to replace it with `subcaption`.

Comment: @Miyase Just as a reminder, it works)

Comment: So far, yes, of course. But there's a reason that the author of subfig declared their own package obsolete, and so many knowledgeable people here recommend avoiding it. It's one thing for a long-time user to be reluctant to change their habit, but another to bring a beginner to use it in 2022.