# Vertically align first image in a 3 image combination [optex]

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, plain-tex, optex

Following the tip from the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646938/258453), I could align three (sub)figures:

```
\def\figure#1#2{\vbox{\hbox{\picw=.45\hsize \inspic{#1.jpg}}\medskip\hbox{\qquad#2}}}

\hbox to\hsize{\figure{S10} {(a) Bird}\hss
               \vbox{\figure {tucano} {(b) caption 2}\bigskip
                     \figure {maria-preta-do-nordeste} {(c) caption 3}}}
```

[image]

However, as the image shows, if the figures are roughly the same size, the first one appears at the bottom, not  in the middle. I guess it can be done using the `\table` macro and some tweaking, but is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\vcenter` from math mode:

```tex
\hbox to\hsize{$\vcenter{\figure{S10}{(a) Bird}}$\hss
               $\vcenter{\figure{tucano}{(b) caption 2}\bigskip
                         \figure{maria-preta-do-nordeste}{(c) caption 3}}$}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `\valign`:

```
\def\figure#1#2{\vbox{\hbox{\picw=.45\hsize \inspic{#1.jpg}}\medskip\hbox{\qquad#2}}}

\noindent
X\dotfill X

\medskip

\hbox to\hsize{%
  \tabskip=0pt
  \valign{%
    \vss#\vss\cr
    \figure{example-image-a} {(a) Bird}\cr
    \noalign{\hfill}
    \figure {example-image-b} {(b) caption 2}\bigskip
    \figure {example-image-c} {(c) caption 3}\cr
  }%
}

\bye
```

[image]