# Subfloat figure arrangment

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to achieve the following figure layout using `\subfloat` but without any success. That is to have one figure one the left side of the page, and other two on the right side, aligned, and as high as the left figure.
[image]

I have the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}

\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{fig1}%
    \label{subfig:fig1}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{fig2}%
    \label{subfig:fig2}}
    \vfill
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{fig3}%
    \label{subfig:fig3}}%
    \caption{my caption.}
    \label{fig:results}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

but what I get is the following:
[image]

as you can see there is a misalignment between figure (a) and the column of figures (b and c).

How can I fix that?

Comment: The first step is to post code here, which DOES compile ... as it's now, we have to guesswork about your preamble ... and can't display any figure ...

Comment: You should show a minimal example from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks. I've just updated the code. Is enough or should I add something more?

Comment: Fine :) Looks good enough for me now. Thank you

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646910/how-can-i-create-this-layout-of-3-subfigures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why using `figure*` for a one-column document, so I add `twocolumn`. If your document is one-column, use `figure`.

There are several ways to solve the problem, I like to use `\valign` (which has no LaTeX interface).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\valign{#\cr
\hbox{\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{example-image}\label{subfig:fig1}}}\cr
\noalign{\hfill}
\hbox{\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth,height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\label{subfig:fig2}}}
\vfill
\hbox{\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\label{subfig:fig3}}}
\cr}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I use `height=1.5cm` just to reproduce the format of your images.

[image]

Comment: It works wonderfully, thanks! I'm using a two-column template, that's why I put `figure*`. I forgot to mention that