Is it possible to add images in this format using subcaption?

I understand how to add images in a (2 X 2) or a (m X n) grid in latex using subcaption, but is it possible to add images in this manner using subcaption?
If not possible, then is there some other package which allows this configuration and also allows cross-referencing?
Here is the MWE that I tried
\usepackage{graphicx} %package for graphics/images
\usepackage{subcaption} %package for subcaptions(Chitran's edit)
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/A.png}
        \phantomsubcaption
        \label{figA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width= \linewidth]{Figures/B.png}
        \phantomsubcaption
        \label{figB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/C.png}
        \phantomsubcaption 
        \label{figC}
    \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/D.png}
        \phantomsubcaption 
        \label{figD}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{(a) fig.A (b) fig.B (c) fig.C (d) fig.D}\label{fig_needed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

What I end up having is something like this

P.S. : Hearty apologies for the imprecise post with no MWE before.

Have you used InkScape for your picture? Excuse me but is not better that you put a minimal working example thus we can better help?

Without minimal working example, I would guess: Mixture of \subcaptionbox or similar and a minipage with two \subcaptionbox or similar inside — if you need sub-caption numbering.

Don't worry in the most absolute way. We are here to help you.

Does this answer your question? Aligned subcaptions: Two small stacked pics left to a large pic

Seee also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646910/how-can-i-create-this-layout-of-3-subfigures

You don't need subfigure if you don't have subcaptions.
I don't have your images, it's up to you to ensure that the heights match.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package for graphics/images
\usepackage{subcaption} %package for subcaptions(Chitran's edit)
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% leave computations to LaTeX

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.24\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16} &
\includegraphics[width=0.24\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16} &
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{example-image-16x9} \\[1ex]
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{example-image-16x9}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{(a)~fig.~A (b)~fig.~B (c)~fig.~C (d)~fig.~D}\label{fig_needed}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


A trick if your images don't really match like the one I used.
I experimented a bit and discovered that 0.27 for the first two pictures and 0.41 for the other two gives almost the sizes we need. Since there is a bit of room in the vertical spacing between the wide pictures, we can make it to be automatically filled.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package for graphics/images

\newlength{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% leave computations to LaTeX
\settoheight{\mylength}{\includegraphics[width=0.27\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16}}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.27\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16} &
\includegraphics[width=0.27\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16} &
\vbox to \mylength{
  \hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.41\columnwidth]{example-image-16x9}}
  \vfil
  \hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.41\columnwidth]{example-image-16x9}}
}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{(a)~fig.~A (b)~fig.~B (c)~fig.~C (d)~fig.~D}\label{fig_needed}

\end{figure}

\end{document}



Thanks dude. The more simpler first version with tabular allowed me with just the solution that I needed.
